# Regex match any string inside quotes if its length is higher than

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

How i could match any string inside quotes if its length is higher than 10?

example:

```
"hi"
"hello"
"something_else"
```

Match just **something_else**, as its length is higher than 10.

I tried:

```
(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1
```

Could match anything inside the quotes, but I'm in doubt about how to set the min length.

Comment: What is the logic of the pattern? Right now the assertion checks for an optional backslash and if it is there, it matches it, which will always succeed as it is optional. Perhaps like this? `(["']).{11,}?\1`  https://regex101.com/r/JHWFlM/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it: `".{11,}"`

For a minimum length of 11, you put `{11,}`

See https://regex101.com/r/tgqec7/2

Answer (score 0):

You can put a range of numbers (including an open-ended range) in curly braces:

`".{11,}"`

Matches at least 11 characters inside quotes